# XML Viewer Web part: filter/setting/javascript/jquery to dynamically point to xml file

Tags: web-part, xslt, xml

perhaps this is a silly question, but is there a way to use a filter, or some script, or a setting or something like that, in SP2010 to allow a user to select various xml documents from a library and have a xml viewer web part apply some xlst?

I like the straightforward simplicity of the xml viewer web part, and have some extensive xml / xsl to use with this, but it is kind of useless without being able to select more than a single xml file at a time....i don't want to have users going in changing setting to achieve that?

though maybe this exists and is easy, i just don't know how?

EDIT: just to clarify, what I would like to be able to do is drop an xml viewer web part on a page, and specify only the xsl stylesheet (within a library; just use link), then have another library web part on the same page that acts as a selection filter for that xml web part. This way more than one single harded coded xml data file could be use (only one at a time) without having to go into the web part and alter the settings of the web part.

is this possible?

Comment: Are you handy with C#? This isn't that difficult to implement (does require a bit of coding black magic, but certainly isn't impossible).

Comment: a bit more than novice? but I would love to learn more about this, and any help you can provide with this above use case would be most appreciated!

Comment: can it be implemented through say silverlight style wsp approach. govern on this implem is really tough and SOM dev is really more trouble than it is worth. but if I could take some approach on my dev, and implement via COM...that would work I believe.

Comment: You'd have to use Web PArt Connections, and I don't think these are available in the Sandbox...